# Changing keyboard mapping

Tags: keyboard, remapping

I'm pretty new to the site. I want to change my keyboard key-mapping. I use Ubuntu 16.4. By keyboard key-mapping I mean that if I type key 'a' I want a different unicode character (or characters) to appear be typed. Is there any code which I can temporarily run to get the work done? Can somebody help me?

Comment: Try `setxkbmap en` and replace en with corresponding language abbreviation. (en is english).

Comment: @JohnRonald in terminal it says 'Error loading new keyboard description'

Comment: You are probably entering wrong language shortcut.